# Ancient Japanese calendar exercise in C++

Tags: c++, math, logic, codeblocks

Exercise:

*In Ancient Japanese calendar was 60-year cycle. Every year was numbered from 1 to 60 and divided into pairs, each of it has it's own color(green, red, yellow, white or black).The colors of the year were distributed as follows:*

- 1, 2, 11, 12, 21, 22, ..., 51, 52 year - green color;
- 3, 4, 13, 14, 23, 24, ..., 53, 54 year - red color;
- 5, 6, 15, 16, 25, 26, ..., 55, 56 year - yellow color;
- 7, 8, 17, 18, 27, 28, ..., 57, 58 year - white color;
- 9, 10, 19, 20, 29, 30, ..., 59, 60 year - black color.

We know that the new 60-year cycle began in 1984 and will end in 2043; 1984's and 1985's were green color year, 1986's and 1987's were red color year, the year 2043's will be black color year.

We know year *m*(1800 < m < 2200). Write a program, which prints out what color is of the year.

P.S. This exercise was not written in English!

Comment: I can tell you that your conditions (in the `if` and `else if`) don't work the way you think they do. Apart from that it's unclear what your question is

Comment: Please refer to the code review sister site for SO

Comment: It looks like a 10 year cycle. For that you could use `auto color_index = ((input - 4) % 10) / 2;` to get the index of an array representing the colors.

Comment: @OneARMINAS Just for your information: We are not here to do your homework

Comment: The exercise, or the version that has been posted, lacks any mention of the [Twelve Earthly Branches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagenary_cycle). Therefore the 10 year cycle is enough to calculate the color. Maybe just add a comment in your code? Is this due on Monday?

Comment: I understanded now that 60 year cycle has in it 10 year cycle. Or something like that. It's not my homework. I just found in a book and wanted to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your list the Color rotates in a 10 years cycle and then has always 2 subsequent years with same color. Given that rule you can calculate an index in a field of year colors.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int base_year = 1984;
    vector<string> colors = { "green", "red", "yellow", "white", "black" };

    int year;
    cout << "Insert year: ";
    cin >> year;

    int offset = year - base_year;
    int index = (offset % 10) / 2;
    if (index < 0) index += colors.size();

    cout << "year offset " << offset << " color index :" << "year color: " << colors[index] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```